# Python: Is there a python module for ssh that supports lots of tunnels?

Tags: python, module, ssh, popen, tunnel

I am writing a program that creates reverse tunnels with ssh.
I am using Popen currently, but I am receiving an error because I have too many arguments.
So my question is:

Is there any python module that supports a lot of tunnels? (Preferably 1000+)

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, but it sounds like you might have an architectural problem that needs solving.

Comment: Instead of using arguments, did you try using a ssh config file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not so much a module as a library, [Twisted.Conch](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/TwistedConch) might be a better approach... but be warned that of all the modules in Twisted, conch can be one of the most intimidating ( atleast IMHO ).